Solving dependencies of an already built library in cmake
I am relatively new to cmake. I want to use the raspicam library in my C++ code. It depends on some othe libraries(mmal) resulting from building userland. In order to link these libraries, inside CMakeLists.txt located in /myproj/raspicam/src I am doing:
FIND_LIBRARY(mmalcore_LIBS NAMES mmal_core PATHS ../../userland/build/lib)

then linking this to my resulting library(libraspicam.so) using
target_link_libraries(raspicam mmalcore_LIBS)

and everything build correctly. Inside /myproj/raspicam/build/src I have my libraspicam.so file. Everything fine up until here. The problem is that I want to use the raspicam library inside /myproj/simpletest_raspicam.cpp . My CMakeLists.txt file here looks like this:
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8) 
project (raspicam_test)
find_library(raspicam_LIBS NAMES raspicam PATHS raspicam/build/src)
message(${raspicam_LIBS})
if( (NOT raspicam_LIBS) )
    message(FATAL_ERROR "raspicam not found")
endif()

include_directories(raspicam/src)
include_directories(/home/mot3clj/testraspicam/userland/build/lib)
link_directories(/home/mot3clj/testraspicam/raspicam/src)
link_directories(/home/mot3clj/testraspicam/userland/build/lib)

add_executable (simpletest_raspicam simpletest_raspicam.cpp)  
target_link_libraries (simpletest_raspicam ${raspicam_LIBS})

The cmake does its job succesfully, however when calling make I am seeing the following output:
/some/path/to/linker: warning: libmmal_core.so, needed by ../raspicam/build/src/libraspicam.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)

and since this is missing I get an error every time a function from here is used.
How can I modify my cmake file so that my build finishes correctly? I thought that since the build for raspicam was successful, the libmmal_core.so library should be linked to it and would not require additional linking.
I have a guess that the runtime linker doesn't find libmmal_core.so I have tried solving this issue by doing
list( APPEND CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "userland/build/lib" )

but I had no success. I think that using find_library again in the second cmake file would solve the issue, but I don't think it's a good solution doing the same operation two times. I have modified some paths in the project downloaded from github changing from /opt/vc/lib to relative paths since I am doing cross compiling for yocto built raspberrypi4.

target_link_directories instructs the linker where to look. In general, try to avoid target_link_libraries with paths instead of library names. (mmal_core in this case)

include_directories and link_directories does not do what you think they do. I would suggest creating a group of CMake projects, one executable and one or more libraries and practice loading them before attempting anything more complex.

Proper CMake would involve an IMPORTED TARGET where you attach the link and include directories to the target and transfer them by linking instead.
